# SEGMENTATION FAULT (SIGSEGV)

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in c++. This is my code. It is working properly in code blocks but when I submitted it to codechef, it is showing a run time error(`SIGSEGV`). Please help!

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long int n, m, x, temp, B1 = 0, B2 = 0;
    long int arr[105];

    cin >> n >> m;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
    while(m--)
    {
        B1 = B2 = 0;
        cin >> x;
        temp = 1;

        while(temp < x)
            if((arr[x] - arr[temp]) > 0)
                B1 = B1 + (arr[x] - arr[temp++]);
            else
                B2 = B2 + (arr[x] - arr[temp++]);
        cout << B1 - B2 << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not read a tutorial, if you are a beginner?

Comment: You haven't shown your input.  If you put some cerr << "temp " << temp << ", x " << x << '\n'; style trace in, you can probably work this out yourself.  And using a vector and at() lets you get an exception when you index outside the valid indices - safer while you're learning.

Answer (score 5):

**For an array of size `N`, valid indexes are between 0 and `N-1`.**

Change this:

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
```

To this:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
```

BTW, you haven't specified the purpose of your program, but I'm guessing that you should probably change `temp=1` to `temp=0` as well...